# How to update solr field attributes

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using solr 4.10. I have indexed few documents in it. Now I want to change boost of few documents. I have found a lot of informations about filed update but nothing about attribute update.

Can anyone give some guide?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you read these links:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Near+Real+Time+Searching

You can update single documents, for example by its id:

```
curl -u user:password http://solr_url/core/update?commit=true -H "Content-type:application/json" -d '[{"solrid":"document_id","attribute":{"set":"new_value"}}]'
```

But there are a few thing you should be aware of, regarding attributes persistence (only those stored will be kept after the update) and specially regarding hard and soft commit.

I believe those links will help you.